# JovoFramework - NEW_USER - tell is not a function

Tags: jovo-framework

I'm using jovo framework (version 1.0.0) and I'm facing the following problem:

In app.js:

```
app.setHandler({
  'NEW_USER': () => {
    this.tell('Hello, I've just installed this skill.');
  }
});
```

I get the following error when a user is new to the skill:

> TypeError: this.tell is not a function

Can't I use this.tell in the NEW_USER?

System Environment:

- Windows 10 Home
- NodeJS: v8.9.1

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi Florian. I just tested it, and apparently it's because of the arrow notation. I got this one to work:

'NEW_USER': function() {
        this.tell('Hello, I\'ve just installed this skill.');
    },

Comment: Thank you very much @JanKönig this solved my issue but opened another. I'll write a new post for that.